# Form Field is not showing in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I added a custom form field
[image: that is Banner Mobile Image and it working fine with me]

[image: but when i clicked in edit option this field is not showing in the form]

here my code is

```
<field name="bannermobileimage">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banners</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Banner Mobile Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item> 
               <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item> 
               <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">bannermobileimage</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">16</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="banners/banners_image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: did you clear the cache? Are you sure that there is no other field with the name `bannermobileimage`? Did you add the field in the same fieldset?

Comment: i did the all above things a couple of times and also check multiple times this is no other field with same name ...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create another controller to upload the Mobile banner Image and change the **Field ID** on that new controller to "bannermobileimage".

Please update the form's UI Component XML for New Controller path. (Assume new controller file name for Mobile banner image upload is "**Mobileupload.php**")

```
<item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="banners/banners_image/mobileupload"/>
</item>
```

To save the new field value in the Database, you may need to update the corresponding Interface and Model class.